# Glitches in Unity pixel art

Tags: unity-game-engine

Some glitches (random lines) appear in my pixel art game which I cannot get rid of.

[image: screenshot]

In the zoomed photo you can see it more clearly.
I checked, anti-aliasing was disabled, I don't know what else to do.

[image: zoomed]

And it seems fine in Scene view, the glitch is only in the Game view.

Here are the settings of the assets.

[image: tilemap]

[image: inspector]

Comment: My first thought is that this is an issue with the sprite sheet in that some of the tiles aren't aligned with the grid properly so a column of pixels from the next sprite in the sheet is bleeding into this one.

Comment: I checked in the Sprite Editor and everything is aligned perfectly.

Comment: are there any spurious objects there?

Comment: Only Empty-s. https://i.imgur.com/musYLo1.jpg

Comment: Could you screenshot the tiles textures and their settings so that we can help you? There are 2 possibilities I can think of from the available info: 1- If you are using a tile atlas, then there could be no padding between the tiles in the atlas. 2- If each tile is a standalone texture, then the textures probably have a "repeat" wrap mode and you should try changing it to "clamp". I hope this helps.

Comment: I updated the question and included the Inspector window capture and the Tilemap. Wrap was set to Clamp, it wasn't the case.
However, there was no padding in atlas, how can I fix that (without touching the asset file)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While developping a 2d game we've encountered a similar problem. [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QW53YIjhQsA) video explains well what's happening and some solutions to fix the problem. Hope it can help you !

Comment: According to StackOverglow guide, good answers should not only include a link. What if the video gets removed? "Provide context for links: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline."

Answer (score 0):

I work with libgdx and tiled map and I had the same problem and I had extra line there,maybe the problem is tile map renderer maybe it put the camera in the float position,but never mind I solved my problem with duplicating the last pixel in my tile,for example each of my tile has 16 pixel,I duplicate the last pixel,my tile became 18 pixels but I defined my tile sheet should has 2 space and 1 margin and I get 16 pixel and the problem solved ,even  if I want to make some background animation with tile map I had to do this,and this problem is just with tile map renderer.